# How to get element one by one using node.js Cheerio

Tags: javascript, node.js, cheerio

I'm making web scraper using Cheerio, Request on Node.js. I used some scrapers, But I don't know jQuery familiar scraper, Cheerio. anyway, Let's see the problem.

**html**

```
<li><a title="FR" class="A">176.31.239.33:8133</a></li>
<li><a title="FR" class="B">87.98.218.86:3128</a></li>
<li><a title="CN" class="A">183.62.60.100:80</a></li>
<li><a title="CN" class="A">183.131.152.227:80</a></li>
<li><a title="CN" class="A">183.238.133.43:80</a></li>
```

I want to pick up elements that have class="A", and then its text `(183.62.60.100:80)`. and then will make array.

```
[ 
{ 'title' : 'FR', 'IP' : '176.31.239.33:8133' }, 
{ 'title' : 'CN', 'IP' : '183.62.60.100:80' },
...
]
```

But I got stucked. I tried...

```
var $ = cheerio.load(html);
var arr = $('a[class=A]').text();
console.log(arr) 

// result is 
// 176.31.239.33:8133183.62.60.100:80183.131.152.227.80

// if I print console.log(arr[0]), the result is just 1
```

The reuslt is not an array, so I can't pick it up one by one. How could I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should iterate through the collection returned by a `jquery/cherrio` selector and get each element's  `title`attribute together with it's inner text. Try:

```
var $ = cheerio.load(html);
var arr = $('a[class=A]');   
var array = [];
arr.each(function() {
    array.push({
        title: $(this).attr('title'),
        IP: $(this).text()
    });
});
```

You can also try to replace `$('a[class=A]')` expression with `$("a.A")`. It looks cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

Cheerio follows jQuery's style of operating on collections first if that's what an aggregator function like `.text()` is called on. If you want the text of each element separately, iterate or map over it.

Here's an alternative to the [existing answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34532394/6243352):

```js
const cheerio = require("cheerio"); // 1.0.0-rc.12

const html = `
<li><a title="FR" class="A">176.31.239.33:8133</a></li>
<li><a title="FR" class="B">87.98.218.86:3128</a></li>
<li><a title="CN" class="A">183.62.60.100:80</a></li>
<li><a title="CN" class="A">183.131.152.227:80</a></li>
<li><a title="CN" class="A">183.238.133.43:80</a></li>
`;
const $ = cheerio.load(html);
const data = [...$("a.A")].map(e => ({
  title: $(e).attr("title"),
  IP: $(e).text(),
}));
console.log(data);
```

It's also possible to use a jQuery-style mapper and `.get()` or `.toArray()` to return the native array:

```js
const data = $("a.A")
  .map((i, e) => ({
    title: $(e).attr("title"),
    IP: $(e).text(),
  }))
  .toArray();
```

Note that the `map`'s arguments are `(index, element)` in jQuery rather than `(element, index)` with the native JS `map`.

Reasons to like this:

- `map` is a specialization of the common iteration idiom:

  ```js
  const result = [];
  array.forEach(e => {
     result.push(transform(e));
  });
  return result;
  ```

  which is cleaner and easier to write as:

  ```js
  const result = array.map(transform);
  ```
- The selector `"a.A"` is usually preferred over `'a[class="A"]'` because `[class="A"]` is very specific. If another class is added, it'll fail. As with `map`, it's simpler to write and read.